# "No such module 'FirebaseInstallations'" issue on ionic capacitor ios build

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to build a capacitor app on xcode and getting this issue "No such module 'Firebase'" when add Firebase into a library' on line "import FirebaseInstallations". there are no firebase library I can find. Any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't follow the setup instructions for the `@capacitor-community/fcm` plugin.  In addition to `npm install @capacitor-community/fcm`, there are about 20 steps you need to perform manually to set this up.

See the [installation guide in the module's README](https://github.com/capacitor-community/fcm#add-google-config-files).  You need to get config files from Apple + Google and then set up each OS (iOS + Android).